# How to put CGContextScaleCTM and CGContextTranslateCTM outside of drawRect?

Tags: ios, drawrect, cgcontext, scaletransform

I am rather beginner at this kind of path drawing, but when displaying a map, I realised that CGContextScaleCTM and CGContextTranslateCTM take up a lot of time inside my drawRect.
That would be good to bring those outside. Since I always draw the same map, I think that should be possible. But how?

Answer (score 0):

could scale like this:

```
CGAffineTransform currentTransform = myView.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, 0.5, 0.5);
[myView setTransform:newTransform];
```

and use CGAffineTransformTranslate in a similar manner for x/y.